# How can I create an army of chickens?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

According to the video below, I can recruit cuccos to assist me in battle.

So far, I've seen a single chicken in some fairy fountains, but there is no clear way to get it to fight alongside me.  I am able to attack it, which in typical Zelda fashion results in me getting attacked by an army of cuccos.  I've also seen a golden chicken in the Adventure Mode, which apparently eats to get stronger.  Attacking it also results in becoming an enemy of the cucco.

How can I get the rage of chickens to become a force for good instead of evil?

Comment: I know one adventure map has you escort a baby Cucco to a mamma cucco and they will join you from there. I only know how to piss them off besides that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been playing a lot of Adventure Mode recently, and here's what I've discovered. There are multiple ways in which Cuccos can be employed in a map, and your strategy for getting them to fight with you differs depending on the scenario.

- In one type of scenario, you have Cucco forces on your side to begin with. In this level, the strategy is simple: you already have a chicken army. Enjoy! The more keeps you take, the stronger your chicken army becomes.
- In one type of scenario, a golden Cucco begins feasting on the blood of the soldiers in the various keeps. As far as I can tell, you cannot turn this Cucco to your side any more than you can turn an enemy officer to your side -- that is to say, if it's not scripted, it ain't happening. Kill the Cucco quickly and move on.
- In one type of scenario, Cuccos are present on the map but unaligned to begin with. This is the type of scenario in which various internet sources claim that if you can get your enemies to hit the Cucco, the birds will flock against the enemies. However, I have done extensive experimentation in square D1, and I have concluded that this is not possible. The Shield Moblins in D1 are happy to hit the Cucco, but despite being smacked around by enemies for a solid minute, the Cucco was not enraged until I accidentally caught him in an AoE of my own. The best you can hope for is not to enrage the Cucco at all. Sorry.
- In one type of scenario, you are tasked with reuniting a baby cucco with his mother. Upon reuniting them, the Cucco forces will join your side, including the mother which is a golden cucco.
- In one type of scenario, Cuccos fight each other over territory. I'm not 100% sure what you do here, because I've only ever seen one Cucco win and then start attacking everyone as a third rogue faction. If I figure out how to turn this to your advantage I'll return and update.
- Using

> Lana's Summoning Gate

weapon, perform a special/Musou attack. Tadah! Cucco army! (Temporarily)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to cause enemies to attack the cucco, but it is a rather tedious process.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get an enemy to attack the Cucco it will cause the Cucco to attack the enemy's but that is it, you can't recruit them.